# React native fontFamily issue when turn on secureTextEntery

Tags: react-native

### issue

---

I have some issue i use fontFamily in style and it works fine when i turn on secureTextEntery fontFamily is set to something else (not default react fontFamily) and place holder font have issue as well

### thing i try

---

I try using short if password.length but it doesn't work well

```
<TextInput style={{fontFamily:'riffic'}} secureTextEntery placeHolder={'password'}\>
```

Comment: This issue is fixed in version 0.64.2 https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v0642 commit: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/cda77c77dd83cba07e6c2e56e938c3e4f7faf8fc

Comment: i try and change version to 64.2 but nothing happen and i still have this issue